# Largest natural number $n$ such that $\int_1^\infty\frac{\log^nx}{e^x}\mathrm dx<1$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Find the largest natural number $n$ such that $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^nx}{e^x}\mathrm dx<1$$

Upon searching on site and google, I found a similar integral:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{e^x}\mathrm dx=-\gamma$$

But the techniques involving solving such integrals is beyond what I've learnt till now. The elementary method I know is to think of some adaptation of squeeze theorem like to search a $f$ such that: $$f>\frac{\ln^nx}{e^x}$$ and $$\int_1^\infty f\mathrm dx = 1$$ But I can't imagine any such $f$ upon hit and trial.

(P.S.: This question came in my class test of applications of derivatives. According to answer key, $n=7$)

Comment: Hello :) Does $\log^2( x) $ mean $\log (x) \cdot\log( x) $ or $\log(\log (x))$? We have $\int_1^\infty e/e^xdx=1$

Comment: Numerically, it looks like the given integral is always less than $1$ for $n\ge 0$, which makes me think there's a typo somewhere. Can you double-check the problem statement (of course, I could've made a mistake instead)?

Comment: @Jochen Of course $\log(x).\log(x)$. Why would it mean otherwise ?

Comment: @VarunVejalla Is it smaller than $1$ for $n=8$ ?  I re-checked and it's verbatim.

Comment: Oops my bad, I was using Desmos as a quick check, and $\log$ there is $\log_{10}$, not $\ln$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I meant $\log$ as $\log_e$. I'll edit it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Notation like $\operatorname{func}^n x$ can mean either exponentiation of the function value or repeated composition of the function. For the trig and hyperbolic trig functions we have an understanding that a positive integer $n$ means exponentiation, not composition. (But $\sin^{-1}$ is another matter.) For any other functions it's best to explain what's meant. Or here you can avoid the ambiguity by just using $(\ln x)^n$.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks. I didn't knew about this notation.

Comment: @An_Elephant, have you reached exponential integrals?

Comment: @Ercanayan What are they? I think I haven't. While according to test, the answer should be elementary but all level of answers are welcome here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*I do not know a simple solution to this problem.*

Consider
$$I_n=\int_1^\infty e^{-x} \,\log ^n(x)\,dx$$ For $n>1$, the explicit solution is gives as a
[Meijer_G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function) (which can express in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions).

$$\color{blue}{I_n=n!\, G_{n,n+1}^{n+1,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1,\cdots,1 \\
 0,0,0,0,\cdots,0  \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)}$$

For sure, this leads to the result.

Comment: Thanks , though all the stuffs in your answer is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: @An_Elephant. This problem became one of my nightmares. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Some helps/remarks (hope you enjoy it):

Using Bernoulli's inequality we have :

$$J=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+4\left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)\right)^{2}}{e^{x}}dx< I_8$$

Using a simple bound we have :

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+4\left(\frac{4\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)}{\sqrt{x}+1}-1\right)\right)^{2}}{e^{x}}dx<J$$

or :

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-3+\frac{16\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)}{\sqrt{x}+1}\right)^{2}}{e^{x}}dx<J$$

or :

$$K=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{9+\frac{16^{2}\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)^{2}}{\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^{2}}-6\cdot16\frac{\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)}}{e^{x}}dx$$

Now we have :

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{9+\frac{29\left(x-1\right)}{\left(x+1\right)}-6\cdot16\frac{\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)}}{e^{x}}dx<K$$

finally :

$$1<\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{9+\frac{29\left(x-1\right)}{\left(x+1\right)}-51\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{\left(x+1\right)}}{e^{x}}dx<K$$

It shows that it cannot be greater than $8=n$

Comment: According to google, bernoulli inequality is : $(1+x)^r>1+rx$ . Can you please elaborate how did you used it in second line ? Thanks, the bounds look quite horrible lol.

Comment: No problem it's $$\ln\left(x\right)>\frac{2\left(x-1\right)}{x+1},x>1$$ use derivative and $x=y^2$

Comment: Thanks but Unfortunately, all went above my head :(

Comment: Do you want more details? I don't want to see you lost with that problem honestly.

Comment: Yes, if you could do, then please. Thanks :)

Comment: Q1. 1st line, why you do $\left(1+4\left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)\right)^{2}<\ln^8x$$$$$ Q2. 2nd line, why you replace $x$ to $\sqrt x$, rather than use $x$$$$$ Q3. Even though it is true that $\frac{4\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)}{\sqrt{x}+1}<\ln x$, but it is **NOT** true that $$\left(1+4\left(\frac{4\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)}{\sqrt{x}+1}-1\right)\right)^{2}<\left(1+4\left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)\right)^{2}$$ Let $x=1.5$ $$\left(1+4\left(\frac{4\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)}{\sqrt{x}+1}-1\right)\right)^{2}=1.91\color{red}>1.89=\left(1+4\left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)\right)^{2}$$

Comment: @MathFail Hi, I have seen you writing many answers of calculus. Please answer my question too.

Comment: @MathFail You totally forgot the integral....which are easy to determine your question are a shame anyway : Q1 $4\cdot 2=8$ Q2 it's inferior to one Q3 it's in term of integral .

Comment: I don't understand. What does anything from this answer have to do with $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\ln x\right)^{n}}{e^{x}}dx$? You're supposed to show that $n=7$ is the largest positive integer that makes the integral less than $1$.

Comment: @Accelerator Hi, I have seen you writing many answers of integration and calculus. Please answer my question too.

Comment: @An_Elephant I appreciate the request, but I don't know how to answer your question. :(

Comment: @Accelerator Hi  , can you please answer my recent question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4741601/1020656 . Thanks!