# Generalise logarithmic integral $ \int_0^1\ln^n (\frac{1-x}{1+x})\mathrm dx$ related to Zeta function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, zeta-functions

Context:

I've been recently putting integrals of some random functions in online calculators for fun. An interesting kind of logarithmic integrals that I observed are as follows :

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\mathrm dx= \frac{\pi^2}{3}=2\zeta(2)\\
&\int_0^1\ln^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\mathrm dx=-9\zeta(3)\\
&\int_0^1\ln^4\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\mathrm dx = \frac{7\pi^4}{15}=42\zeta(4)\\
&\int_0^1\ln^5\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\mathrm dx=-225\zeta(5)\\
&\int_0^1\ln^6\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\mathrm dx=\frac{31\pi^6}{21}= 1395\zeta(6)
\end{align}

Question:

How can we generalise this for :

$$I_n = \int_0^1\ln^n\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\mathrm dx$$

Notation: The superscript at logarithm means for exponentiation.

Comment: Also, why did you write $\frac{4185\, \zeta(6)}{3}$ instead of $1395\, \zeta(6)$?

Comment: @StevenClark Sorry, I thought it wouldn't be divisible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\ln^n\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\overset{x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x} }{dx}\\
=&\ 2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n x}{(1+x)^2}dx= 2\int_0^1\ln^n x \ d\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\\
\overset{ibp}=& -2n\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{n-1} x}{1+x}dx
=-2n\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{n-1} x}{1-x} {d}x-\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln^{n-1} x}{1-x^2} \overset{x^2\to x}{dx}\right)\\
=&-2n \left(1- \frac1{2^{n-1}}\right) \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{n-1} x}{1-x} {d}x 
= 2n!(-1)^{n}\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right) \zeta(n)
\end{align}

Comment: Hey, could explain the final equality a bit more? Or is it a well known identity? If the latter is true, could you point me a direction on where to read more about it, seems quite interesting

Comment: @Fotis - see the added steps

Comment: Amazing how changing the denominator from $1+x$, to $1-x$ and $1-x^2$ works out so nicely. Great solution, thank you for the added steps!

Comment: Thanks ! Can you guide me how those substitutions came to your mind ?

Comment: Also , will the first term in IBP vanish to zero only when $n$ is integer ? Thanks !

Comment: @An_Elephant - The substitution $x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ is well known for integrals over $(0,1)$. The 1st term of IBP $\frac{x\ln^n x}{1+x}$ vanishes at both $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Quanto The partial fraction, as said, was nicely done. Thanks !